# No internet connexion only on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, malware

I have an issue with Chrome today : impossible to connect on any site. Other browsers works, except Chrome. I launch malwareByte and it found a trojan. I removed it, uninstall chrome, reinstall it (several times). I change the chrome parameters, from proxy settings to global settings. But it still the same.

Somebody have a clue ? I search on the net, try different solutions, but still nothing :/

I am on windows 8.1, wifi connexion.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i found a solution. Something i already try, but the wrong way. I have to run the command *netsh winsock reset* but with command as administrator, not the windows+R command. Then restart computer.
Hope it will help somebody as well